# Is Skype, PDF Reader called web apps

Tags: macos, window, web

I am confused about what is web apps?

Is responsive website(on desktop and mobile looking good) called web apps or Desktop apps like Skype, Notepad, PFD reader called web apps? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Apps (Web Applications) are programs that is stored in a Remote Server, not in your local Drive. It doesn't have to be installed in your device.
The word "Web" suggest the usage of a browser so you can communicate with it's servers. Usually it can be accessed through multiple browsers.

My understanding is, "Skype for Desktop" is a Desktop App.
And "web.skype.com" is a Web App.

Hope this helps even a bit.